# Querying Cassandra data using Spark SQL in Java

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, apache-spark-sql, spark-cassandra-connector

For Querying Cassandra data using Spark SQL in Java, I come across 2 documentation from datastax with version [4.6](https://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.6/datastax_enterprise/spark/sparkSqlJava.html) and [5.0](https://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-dse/datastax_enterprise/spark/sparkSqlJava.html)

The documentation for 5.0 recommends **HiveContext** while 4.6 docs recommends **CassandraSQLContext** . Which one should i use ? I am using **Apache Cassandra 3.9**

Comment: if you are using apache cassandra, you must have installed spark... DSE 4.6 comes with spark 1.4.x while DSE 5.0 comes with 1.6.x. In case you are using spark 2.0 then SQLContext and Hivecontext are bundled into sparksession

Comment: I am using spark 2.1. Can you please point me to an example please ?

Comment: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#upgrading-from-spark-sql-16-to-20...    http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#starting-point-sparksession

Answer (score 1):

I think that if your are going to use 5.0 version there will be not CassandraSQLContext - it was removed since 4.7.

Comment: What if I am using Apache Cassandra 3.9 ?

Comment: It depends on which version of DataStax Enterprise you use - do you have any or you have cassandra standalone? if cassandra and spark are standalone try to follow https://coderwall.com/p/o9bkjg/setup-spark-with-cassandra-connector (module developed by DataStax) using only spark-cassandra-connector